# How to scroll a specific window in a webpage with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to like all the messages in a chat and to do that I need to scroll through the messages. Only 12 messages are visible if I don't scroll. I need to scrolls through the messages chat by a certain amount each time (lets call the value x). I know how to scroll through a web page, but how do you scroll through a window in a web page? [Picture of Instagram chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZz2d.png). I have searched this question but I haven't found anything on it.

Code so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
#accesses opened chrome page
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:1234")#code for the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)#uses the chromedriver
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/direct/t/340282366841710300949128464764092447354")#opens website
sleep(5)

messages = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._acqt._acqu")
i = 0

sleep(3)

for i in range(len(messages)):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(messages[i]).perform()
    sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._abm0._abl_").click()
    sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Like']").click()
    i+=1
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use js to scroll through the element.

**Sample Code**

```
 xpath_element = "//aside[@class='sidebar mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2']//div[@class='mCSB_container']" #Xpath of inner scoll view
 fBody = driver1.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath_element)

 scroll = 0 #number of times to run the scroll function
 while scroll < 3:  # this will scroll 3 times
     driver1.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',
                                 fBody)
      scroll += 1
      # add appropriate wait here, of course. 1-2 seconds each
      sleep(2)
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)